# Minimize the sum of exponentially increasing values with a product constraint

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I would like to minimize
$$\sum^N_i \sqrt[2^i]{x_i} = x_0 + \sqrt{x_1} + \sqrt[4]{x_2} + \cdots$$
subject to the constraints
$$1 = \prod^N_i x_i = x_0x_1x_2\cdots $$
and
$$x_i \in (0, 1]$$

Is this even a well defined problem? I am a bit out of my mathematical depth here.

I know if I didn't have the roots, then I'm asking how to minimize the sum of side lengths of a hypercube with constant volume. That problem is solved by setting all sides equal to one another.

For N=2:

$$
x_1 = \frac{1}{x_0} \\
x_0 + x_0^{-1/2}
$$

Take a derivative, set to zero (knowing $x_0$ cannot be zero):

$$
0 = 1 + 1/2 * x_0^{-3/2} \\
{(-2)}^{-2/3} = x_0 \\
1/\sqrt[3]{4} = x_0 = 0.629\cdots
$$

But now $x_1$ is outside the domain!

Another way I thought to approach this was starting with all set to 1. How would I perturb this to improve my minimum? If I halve $x_0$, I must double $x_1$. The sum is now:

$$
1/2 + \sqrt{2} = \frac{1 + 2\sqrt{2}}{2}
$$

Which is indeed slightly less than the original sum of two. I suppose I could repeat this ad infinitum, and bring $x_0$ as close to zero as possible?

Any pointers on how to tackle this problem are much appreciated!

Comment: The only solution to $\prod_{i=1}^N x_i=1$ and $x_i\in(0,1]$ for all $i$ is $x_i=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: Ah, absolutely! I was trying to simplify the problem for presentation and I overdid it. In fact I have a constant $C$ that the product must be equal to. The constant lies in (0, 1] as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x_0+x_1^{\frac 12}+x_2^{\frac 14}+x_3^{\frac 18}+...+x_N^{\frac{1}{2^N}}=$$$$x_0+\frac 12x_1^{\frac 12}+\frac 12x_1^{\frac 12}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+..$$

Now by $AM-GM$:

$x_0+\frac 12x_1^{\frac 12}+\frac 12x_1^{\frac 12}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+\frac 14x_2^{\frac 14}+..\geq (1+2+2^2+...+2^N)\sqrt[1+2+2^2+...+2^N]{x_0x_1x_2...x_n \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{2^i}}}$$